# Cuda kernel work very slow

Tags: cuda

I have a problem with accelerate my cuda kernel. It looks that kernel works singly thread. Every thread waiting for previously thread. It doesn't work parallel.

Here is my kernel (I modify library LibTom for Cuda kernel)

```
__global__ void kernel(char* BiExponent, int lines)
{


    const int threadID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(threadID<1000){


         mp_int BiNumber; //various from LibTom
         mp_int RNumber;
         mp_int ANumber;
         mp_int MNumber;
         mp_int TempNumber;
         mp_init_device(&RNumber);
         mp_init_device(&ANumber);
         mp_init_device(&MNumber);
         mp_init_device(&TempNumber);
         mp_init_device(&BiNumber);
         mp_read_radix_device(&RNumber, "100648686727131257488671170806992645347098870006145705670894593595064198763504906829344253213869592972491529868272101131220921074193778137252965944155929765587582637231372264910012095142603377767870875822235936330880194126549443874542394830706956638044950273189050162374717380508672959124318834975983480937576",10);
         mp_read_radix_device(&ANumber, "39805067790951086730573861588172121787196543962580983242598202413750011891252460890446709601730030154661775311984755147556289281733978635511703976267279217024606927800989962204783456250825578178354787716873876536014210063984216741307040544888447847197648475195752689213083224036785420625437224428658490304276",10);
         mp_read_radix_device(&MNumber, "129135516335051440235803237491679224882957576030599162234748304648924718545589827797866156951847154321645009878340207570056281485244329202363518578978799475118300745910542939512857296428327440920812107991347416747733387762031164387998805210106456861835748765549471962882426089437101578019500113090139371006775",10);
         mp_read_radix_device(&TempNumber, "0",10);
         char* cstr  = new char[YDIM];
            for(int i=0; i<YDIM; i++){  
                cstr[i] = BiExponent[(threadID*YDIM)+i];
            }
         mp_read_radix_device(&BiNumber,cstr ,10);
         mp_exptmod_device(&ANumber, &BiNumber, &MNumber,&TempNumber); //TEMP = (A^Bi)mod M
         if(mp_cmp_device(&RNumber,&TempNumber)==MP_EQ){ // IF(TEMP==R)
            printf("TRUE\n");
         }
         mp_clear_device(&BiNumber);
         mp_clear_device(&RNumber);
         mp_clear_device(&MNumber);
         mp_clear_device(&ANumber);
         mp_clear_device(&TempNumber);
         delete [] cstr;    
        //      printf("x = %d\n", threadID);


    }}
```

start kernel in host:

```
kernel <<< 1024, 1 >>> (dev_Bi2dChar, lines);
```

Operation runs for 1000 numbers: 80s. It's very slow and I don't know when it is a bug. :/ I need some tips how I can the apps accelerate.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 1024 blocks of 1 thread when using:
`kernel <<< 1024, 1 >>>`

Is this really what you want? I would suggest to create 1 block with 1024 threads instead:
`kernel <<< 1, 1024 >>>`.

Comment: `kernel <<<1,1024>>> or <<<2,512>>>, <<<8,128>>> ,...` doesn't work (/kernel.cu:4545 code=30(cudaErrorUnknown))

Comment: what is your card model?

Comment: my card is nvidia geforce gt555M

Comment: The CC of GT 555M is 2.1 and Fermi architecture. You should be able to launch with <<<1,1024>>> [Check here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)